Setting up Bayes theorem for Bayesian regression
I'm trying to write down a posterior distribution as it relates to having observed a Gaussian process, $y(\cdot)\sim \mathcal{GP}(\mu(\cdot),k(\cdot,\cdot))$, with mean $\mu$ and covariance kernel $k$. I will write down my thought process and I would appreciate any feedback.
By definition, $y$ being a Gaussian process means that $y(x_{1}),y(x_{2}),\dots y(x_{m})$ is Gaussian, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
y(x_{1}) \\
y(x_{2}) \\
\vdots \\
y(x_{m})
\end{bmatrix}\sim \mathcal{N}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu(x_{1}) \\
\mu(x_{2}) \\
\vdots \\
\mu(x_{m})
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
k(x_{1},x_{1}) & k(x_{1},x_{2}) & \dots & k(x_{1},x_{m})\\
k(x_{2},x_{1}) & k(x_{2},x_{2}) & \dots & k(x_{2},x_{m})\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
k(x_{m},x_{1}) & k(x_{m},x_{2}) & \dots & k(x_{m},x_{m})
\end{bmatrix}
\right).
\end{align}
I am not confident about my following reasoning and so criticism/feedback is welcome :).
For simplicity, I will consider just $x_{1},x_{2}$ and that $y(x_{2})$ has been observed to be a number $v$. For notational simplicity I use $y_{1}=y(x_{1})$ and $y_{2}=y(x_{2})$. I would like to now determine the posterior probability density function $\rho_{\text{post}}(y_{1}|y_{2}=v)$, which seems appropriate to use Bayes rule.
\begin{align}
\rho_{\text{post}}\left(y_{1}|y_{2}=v\right)\propto \rho(y_{1})\cdot\rho\left(y_{2}=v|y_{1}\right)
\end{align}
So, it seems that $\rho(y(x_{1}))$ is the prior marginal distribution on $y_{1}$ and can be obtained as
\begin{align}
\rho(y_{1})=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\rho(y_{1},y_{2})\mathrm{d}y_{2},
\end{align}
where $\rho(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the joint prior probability distribution
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1} \\
y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\sim
\mathcal{N}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu(x_{1}) \\
\mu(x_{2})
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
k(x_{1},x_{1}) & k(x_{1},x_{2}) \\
k(x_{2},x_{1}) & k(x_{2},x_{2})
\end{bmatrix}
\right).
\end{align}
and $\rho(y_{2}=v|y_{1})$ is a likelihood distribution corresponding to how likely it is to observe $y_{2}=v$. Let's assume a zero mean Gaussian distribution for the observation process, that corresponds to random measurement noise, so that $((y_{2}-v)|y_{1})\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_{n}^{2})$. I can work out the math from here, but I wanted to get feedback at this point to make sure that there aren't any issues with my logic.

I am not sure if I understand how you treat the observation noise, but up to this part your reasoning seems correct to me.
Below I suggest to directly employ the formula for conditional Gaussian distributions, which is quite handy when working with Gaussian processes.
No observation noise
Let's focus first on the case where there is no observation noise at all.
We consider a Gaussian process $(Y_x) \sim \mathcal{GP}(\mu, k)$. Writing $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ for random variables corresponding to locations $x_1$ and $x_2$ (i.e., $Y_1 = Y_{x_1}$ and $Y_2 = Y_{x_2}$. It's a slight abuse of notation), we have:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Y_1\\
Y_2
\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal N\!\left( m, \Sigma \right),
$$
where $m_i = \mu(x_i)$ is the mean vector and $\Sigma_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)$ is the covariance matrix.
If $Y_2$ was observed to have value $v$, we are interested in finding the conditional distribution $Y_1\mid (Y_2=v)$. This is a normal distribution with analytically tractable mean and covariance:
$$
Y_1 \mid (Y_2=v) \sim \mathcal N\left(m_1 + \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}r(v-m_2), (1-r^2) \sigma_1^2 \right),
$$
where $\sigma_i = \sqrt{\Sigma_{ii}}$ and $r = \mathrm{Corr}(Y_1, Y_2) = \Sigma_{12}/(\sigma_1 \sigma_2)$.
Adding the observation noise
Now we want to model the situation where our observation is not perfect: we do not see $Y_2$ directly, but rather $Y_2' \mid Y_2 \sim \mathcal N(Y_2, \sigma^2_n)$. What does it mean? We are actually interested in modelling the distribution
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Y_1\\
Y_2'
\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal N\!\left( m, \Sigma' \right),
$$
where $\Sigma'_{11} = \Sigma_{11} = \sigma_1^2$, $\Sigma'_{22} = \Sigma_{22} + \sigma_n^2 = \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_n^2$ and $\Sigma'_{12} = \Sigma_{12}$ (the last equality may be a bit puzzling: the covariance did not change. Proof follows e.g., by writing $Y_2' = Y_2 + E_2$, where $E_2\sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_n^2)$ is assumed to be independent of $X_1$).
We can now use very similar formula as the one above (with $\sigma_2' = \sqrt{\Sigma_{22}'} = \sqrt{\sigma_2^2 + \sigma_n^2}$ and $r' = \Sigma'_{12} / (\sigma_1\sigma_2')$) to obtain $Y_1 \mid (Y'_2 = v)$.
This represents the posterior distribution on the "ground-truth" $Y_1$.
However, if we think about possible values of the measurements, the situation differs! Namely, to model plausible observations, we should think about $Y'_1 = Y_1 + E_1$, where $E_1 \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_n^2)$ is the observational noise. This is, again, a Gaussian distribution (with unchanged mean and larger variance, which is easy to calculate).
Observation noise once again
Let's try to model $Y'_1 \mid (Y'_2 = v)$ once again. We assume the "ground-truth" values to be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Y_1\\
Y_2
\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal N\!\left( m, \Sigma \right),
$$
similarly as above (using the mean function $\mu$ to define $m$ and the kernel function $k$ to define $\Sigma$), but in this case we additionally define the variables corresponding to the errors:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E_1\\
E_2
\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal N\!\left( \mathbf{0}, \sigma^2_n I \right).
$$
Now, as $Y'_i = Y_i + E_i$, we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Y'_1\\
Y'_2
\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal N\!\left( m, \Sigma + \sigma^2_n I \right)
$$
and we can directly calculate the observational distribution $Y'_1 \mid (Y'_2 = v)$.
On addition of kernels
This paragraph may perhaps be confusing and can be skipped at a first reading. I just wanted to have a digression about addition of independent Gaussian processes.
Everything written above works even if $x_1 = x_2$, which implies that $Y_1 = Y_2$. In this case:

without the noise, $Y_1 \mid (Y_2 = v)$ degenerates to the Dirac distribution with a single atom at $v$. It has zero variance.
$Y_1 \mid ( Y'_2 = v)$ has non-zero variance, as we do not observe $Y_2$ directly, but rather its noisy version $Y'_2$.
$Y'_1 \mid (Y'_2 = v)$ has even a larger variance, as errors $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent.

However, if we assume that $x_1\neq x_2$, we can introduce a new Gaussian process $(E_t) \sim \mathcal{GP}(0, \sigma_n^2\delta)$, where
$$
  \sigma_n^2 \delta(x, x') = \begin{cases}  \sigma_n^2  &\text{ if } x=x'\\ 0 &\text{ otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
is the kernel function corresponding to the white noise. (This breaks when $x_1 = x_2$ as in this case we formally have $E_1 = E_2$, rather than having independent errors as considered above).
In this case, we can define variables $Y'_x = Y_x + E_x$, which form a newGaussian process! Namely,
$$(Y'_x) \sim \mathcal{GP}(\mu, k + \sigma^2_n\delta).$$
Generally, if $(A_x) \sim \mathcal{GP}(\mu_A, k_A)$ and $(B_x) \sim \mathcal{GP}(\mu_B, k_B)$ are two independent Gaussian processes, then $(A_x + B_x) \sim \mathcal{GP}(\mu_A + \mu_B, k_A + k_B)$ is a new Gaussian process.
To summarise, when we do not have multiple observations at the same point, we can directly incorporate Gaussian noise into a Gaussian process.

I appreciate this thorough response. Conceptually I like how you've separated the "ground truth" random variables and the random variables which are associated to noisy observations. This helps clarify things for me.

Thank you, I am happy you liked it! I think this point of view is in Chapter 2 of the Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning book.
